# Splunk Forwarder-->Monitoring/Capturing of Specific Events?

Tags: logs, monitoring

Currently Running CentOS7.

I am currently running into an issue with Splunk forwarders. I need to be able to monitor the following for all Linux machines. Some of the following may only apply to windows machines (which I am also monitoring but still posting to see if it's something that can be done"

- File Access Denials - Google had mentioned `auditd` for this part?
- Logon Denials
- Security Group Changes - May just be group changes
- Enabling/Disabling (Add/Remove) of user accounts
- Files/Folders/and Directory permission changes
- User Logons/User Logoffs

I know the line I need to add these is `/opt/splunkforwarder/bin/splunk add monitor` followed by the path to specific logs. What I currently have is monitoring `/var/log/` (simple enough) to capture everything else. But if you all have had any experience using Splunk Forwarders, please let me know if there is a better way to monitor this type of activity

Answer (score 0):

Found out this can be done by configuring the audit.rules file found `/etc/audit/rules.d/audit.rules.` I will post the configuration file as it may come in handy for future users encountering the same issue. The only thing I need to do now is configure the Splunk forwarder to capture this information now.

```
#NOTE-IF YOU HAVE A 32-BIT SYSTEM YOU MUST CHANGE b64->b32 USE "%s/b64/b32/"

# This file contains the auditctl rules that are loaded
# whenever the audit daemon is started via the initscripts.
# The rules are simply the parameters that would be passed
# to auditctl.

# First rule - delete all
-D

# Increase the buffers to survive stress events.
# Make this bigger for busy systems
-b 1024

# Feel free to add below this line. See auditctl man page
#Record events that modify account information
-w /etc/group -p wa -k identity
-w /etc/passwd -p wa -k identity
-w /etc/gshadow -p wa -k identity
-w /etc/shadow -p wa -k identity
-w /etc/security/opasswd -p wa -k identity

#Record events that modify the network configuration
-a exit,always -F arch=b64 -S sethostname -S setdomainname -k system-locale
-w /etc/issue -p wa -k system-locale
-w /etc/issue.net -p wa -k system-locale
-w /etc/hosts -p wa -k system-locale
-w /etc/sysconfig/network -p wa -k system-locale

#Record logon and logout Events
-w /var/log/faillog -p wa -k logins
-w /var/log/lastlog -p wa -k logins

#Record process and session initiation information
-w /var/run/utmp -p wa -k session
-w /var/log/btmp -p wa -k session
-w /var/log/wtmp -p wa -k session

#Record discretionary access control permission modification events
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S chmod -S fchmod -S fchmodat -F auid>=500 -F auid!=4294967295 -k perm_mod

#Record discretionary access control permission modification events
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S chmod -S fchmod -S fchmodat -F auid>=500 -F auid!=4294967295 -k perm_mod
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S chown -S fchown -S fchownat -S lchown -F auid>=500 -F auid!=4294967295 -k perm_mod
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S setxattr -S lsetxattr -S fsetxattr -S removexattr -S lremovexattr -S fremovexattr -F auid>=500 -F auid!=4294967295 -k perm_mod

#Record unauthorized access attempts to files unsuccessful
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S creat -S open -S openat -S truncate -S ftruncate \
-F exit=-EACCES -F auid>=500 -F auid!=4294967295 -k access
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S creat -S open -S openat -S truncate -S ftruncate \
-F exit=-EPERM -F auid>=500 -F auid!=4294967295 -k access

#Record information on exporting to Media (successful)
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S mount -F auid>=500 -F auid!=4294967295 -k export

#Record files deletion events by User (successful and unsuccessful)
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S unlink -S unlinkat -S rename -S renameat -F auid>=500 \
-F auid!=4294967295 -k delete

#Record system administrator actions
-w /etc/sudoers -p wa -k actions

#Record information on kernel module loading and unloading
-w /sbin/insmod -p x -k modules
-w /sbin/rmmod -p x -k modules
-w /sbin/modprobe -p x -k modules
-a always,exit -S init_module -S delete_module -k modules
```